# how to use shell environment variables with setenvif directive in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

We have an application ABC which was developed in Oracle Forms 10g.
Application is hosted in IBM AIX. example server "itabc123" is the hostname.
On the server there are files which are available to the user for download.
example location : "/home/abc/outward/"
Alias for the above directory has been created in httpd.conf :
Alias /abc-dir/ "/home/abc/outward/"
From the Application, the call is made as a URL :
"http : // itabc123:7778 /abc-dir/"

I need to have this URL open only when it is invoked from the Application ABC, and it should not be opened when the URL is directly called from the Browser.

I have created a shell environment variable CALL_FROM_ABC and set the value to Y in the env file.

i want to use the above variable in the setenvif directive to control access to the above URL.

is this syntax correct below :
"
SetEnvIf CALL_FROM_ABC Y let_me_in

<
   Options Indexes Multiviews
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
   Allow from env=let_me_in
>
"
Do i need to user passEnv here ?

Kindly help.

Thanking you,